# Editing a variable length list within another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, variable-length

Can Steven Sanderson's approach [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) be modified to edit a variable length collection within another variable length collection **without dirty hacks**?

The problem is that when there is one collection within another the prefix for the fields in child items omit the parent collections prefix (and more importantly the index) in Steven's approach.

Assuming that I know what the name of the parent collection, I can pass it on to the child collection but I dont see anyway of passing in the index of the parent item to **prepend** to the childrens fields although its available in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this helpful.

http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/

Cheers